# how to give access for users (editors actually only for one specific editor such as id is '3333') to leaky paywall's subscribers list - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

Currently I'm looking for a way to give access to the subscribers list which is belongs to the Leaky Paywall plugin.

[image]

The main goal is that when the editor (3333) will login then he should have access the subscribers list like the administrator has since here the administrator has the option to edit the subscriber's information on admin area. I need to give same access for that specific editor so that he can edit all the informations for any subscriber from the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this.
1. Let Editor to manage users. Here is an article you try: [let editor manage users](https://isabelcastillo.com/editor-role-manage-users-wordpress)
2. Create custom create custom user role, and add capabilities to this custom user role so that it can manage subscriber list. Basically, you can just combine https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role and example from 1.

For example: let's say your new user role is `user_manager`. When editor (3333) will login assign him/here to `user_manager` so that he/she will have editor capabilities and also can manage subscriber lists.

I will really recommend to user option 2.